# Swift - Music from in app to system on button click

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

At the moment I have a check in my app to see if iTunes is playing, and if it is, to proceed with iTunes music and not play the in game music. If iTunes is not playing anything, then to play the in game music.

I am trying to incorporate this into 2 functions and have a button that switches between:

- Play iTunes rather in game music
- Play in game music rather iTunes

This is currently in my viewDidLoad()

```
    let check = isPlaying()
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("music.mp3", ofType: nil)!
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        if check == false {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            music = sound
            sound.play()
        }
    } catch { }
```

The isPlaying() function

```
func isPlaying() -> Bool {
    let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
    if musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing {
        ingame = false;    
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I tried to incorporate the previous code into a function that will be triggered by a button:

```
func playInGameMusic() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("music.mp3", ofType: nil)!
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        music = sound
        sound.play()
        ingame = true
    } catch { }
}
```

However, I have no idea how to go about my playSystemMusic() function. Is there a way to *resume* iTunes from within my app? I understand their is an MPMusicPlayerController class, but I am not sure what I am supposed to use to make iTunes play from a button within my app.

Any guidance is appreciated, thanks.